# How to set single OnItemClickListener to multiple Gridviews

Tags: android, performance, listview, gridview

I have multiple gridviews in single class, so how do I set single OnItemClickListener to multiple gridviews instead of setting like below on individual gridviews.

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
    }
});
```

Comment: the only way is to implement onItemClickListener in your activity and set every gridView: gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the Listener at top level as

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate() {
       gridView_1.setOnClickListener(this);
       gridView_2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.grid_view_1:
                break;
            case R.id.grid_view_2:
                break;
        }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can implements onItemClickListener in your activity and set to your gridview this implement, like:  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
because you have several gridview, for switch between them, you can make a switch-case in your onItemClick method by view.getId().